# What if we apply a force to stop object on a frictionless surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

A force is exerted on an object for an instant. Will the object constantly accelerate, or will it gain a fixed velocity?

Comment: Echoing @PM 2Ring's comment: Do you mean [an _instant_ rather than an _instance_](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/220028)?

Comment: I have corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If by “gains” a constant  velocity you mean the object was originally at rest, and then moves at constant velocity, then by definition it has undergone an acceleration, regardless of how briefly. However that acceleration will last only as long as the force is exerted.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

If the force is applied continuously, the object will keep accelerating forever. If the force is applied for a period of time t, then the object will attain a constant velocity.